# Grep / RegExp help

Tags: grep

I apologize if this is a really stupid question. I have data in the format:

```
etc etc etc <span>etc etc etc</span> etc etc etc
etc etc etc <span>etc etc etc</span> etc etc etc
etc etc etc <span>etc etc etc</span> etc etc etc
```

Is there a way to grep each line for a match that falls outside of the span tags on either side?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A string that is present but only if it's not present within the span tags?

Comment: i just need to find all the lines where a specific string occurs outside of the tag -- if it shows up inside, it's fine but it's not considered a match.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "\(StringGoesHere.*<span>.*</span>\)\|\(<span>.*</span>.*StringGoesHere\)"
```

This just tests for `StringGoesHere` before the span tags, and again after the span tags.  This won't work if there is more than 1 set of span tags per line, and also won't work if the line doesn't have any span tags.

Comment: Correct, though a small verbal explanation might help.

Answer (score 0):

use gawk if you have it (state your OS next time)

```
gawk 'BEGIN{
    RS="</span>"
    FS="\n"
}
{
  m=split($0,a,"<span>")
  if( a[1] ~ /word/){
    print "found: "a[1]" in line: "NR
  }
} ' file
```

output

```
$ cat file
word <span> word blah</span> word
word <span> word
          blah</span>
word etc <span> word blah</span> etc

$ ./shell.sh
found: word  in line: 1
found:  word
word  in line: 2
found:
word etc  in line: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try sed:

```
sed 's:<span>.*</span>::' <FILE>
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`grep "SearchString" | grep -v "<span>.*SearchString.*</span>"`

should find any line at all with `SearchString`, then remove the lines where `SearchString` is inside `<span> ... </span>`.